# Embed website from localhost in an iframe media screen not work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a website from `localhost` run with `ip`.
I want to test by embeding it into `<iframe>` and my media screen not work.
When I use query `[alert(" " + $(window).width() + " x "+ $(window).height());]` it shows difference size.
Example Galaxy S8 embeded into iframe screen size `300px x 150px` and not embed `980px x 1796px`.

What should I do for media screen?

Comment: You have to set the size of the `iframe`.

Comment: Yes already set.

Comment: Please share the code in the `jsfiddle`.  $(window).width() and $(window).height() returns of the screen width and height. So it returns 300px*150px because `Galaxy S8` screen has that size.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
  @media only screen 
      and (max-width : 280px) 
      and (max-height : 679px){
       h1 {
        color: red;
       }
      }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  alert(" " + $(window).width() + " x "+ $(window).height());
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Hello World</h1>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Before I embed into iframe.

Comment: The above `code` is an embedded page?  Please share your code here , https://jsfiddle.net/hkudjo6r/1/

Comment: <body style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
 <div style="left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 0px; position: relative; padding-bottom: 62.45%;">
<iframe src="http://ip_from_child/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"></iframe></div>
</body>

Comment: Please share your code here https://jsfiddle.net/hkudjo6r/1/  and let me know the last url when you save.